# Error while trying to install websocket in laravel using composer require beyondcode/laravel-websockets

Tags: laravel, composer-php, guzzle

I'm facing a composer error while installing a websocket in my laravel project. My intention is to install this websocket and use it for real-time notifications,
but I'm facing an error after issuing an installation command. Below here is what I'm facing:

```
  Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.12.0
- Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/psr7 2.1.0
- Installation request for beyondcode/laravel-websockets ^1.12 -> satisfiable by beyondcode/laravel-websockets[1.12.0, 1.x-dev].
- Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/psr7 2.1.0
- beyondcode/laravel-websockets 1.x-dev requires guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.5 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.7.0, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.8.0, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.8.1, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.8.2, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.8.3, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.x-dev, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.5.0, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.5.1, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.5.2, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.6.0, 2.1.0].
- Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/psr7[1.6.1, 2.1.0].
- Installation request for guzzlehttp/psr7 (locked at 2.1.0) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/psr7[2.1.0].
```

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue please..

Comment: Especially: any of your other packages seems to require `guzzlehttp/psr7` in v2, while the package you want to require now depends on `guzzlehttp/psr7` in v1. You could check which one is the culprit, or ask the maintainers of `beyondcode/laravel-websockets` to release a new version that is compatible

Comment: change  guzzlehttp version in composer.js and run comoser update
   "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",

Comment: Thank you @Usman, I have succeed to install beyondcode/laravel-websockets after downgrading "guzzlehttp/guzzle" version as you have suggested, by for me it was required version "^1.5".

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade the guzzlehttp/guzzle version

Do changes in composer.json
These are according to **Laravel 8** and **PHP 8.0**

Try downgrading or upgrading until it starts work.

> "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
>
> "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.12"
>
> "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
> "laravel/framework": "^8.40",